# Is there a CCBWriter to compliment CCBReader?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, spritebuilder, cocosbuilder

I was wondering if there is a method in cocos2d for saving a given CCNode such as a CCScene to a CCBFile (*.ccb). I've been googling and searching documentation and various fora with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a generally usable CCBWriter.

CCB files are created only by SpriteBuilder and its predecessor CocosBuilder. Both have classes that write out CCB files in text .ccb and binary .ccbi formats.

You could look at the source code to analyze the format but the writer classes dependon the editor classes and can not be used as a general save/load feature in an app.